# If PHP's mysql extension supposedly does not support transactions like mysqli, why do I see people using it for transactions online?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, mysqli

I was reading about mysql transactions and I was under the impression that you had to use either mysqli or PDO in order to create transactions.  However, I see all over stack exchange and other sites examples that use the mysql extension like this:

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
$rollback=0

if (!mysql_query($query1)){
$rollback=1
}

if (!mysql_query($query2)){
$rollback=1
}

if (!mysql_query($query3)){
$rollback=1
}

if ($rollback == 1){
mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}
else{
mysql_query("COMMIT");
}
```

What is the difference between doing it this way and using the "special" mysqli specific functions mysqli::rollback and mysqli::commit?

Also, what happens if the php script crashes (IE my app server crashes etc), does the DB server automatically rollback the transaction after a set timeperiod?

Similarly, what happens if the DB server crashes before mysql_query("COMMIT")? Would the transaction be "rolled back"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's also perfectly legal and is using MySQL statements directly to implement transaction.

And frankly, I don't see any improvements by using the mysqli syntax. It's a failed abstraction since it maps 1:1 on MySQL only. It would make more sense to use the higher level syntax in [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php), since it will map with a different syntax according to the underlying DB.

However, as Hakre says: mysqli is preferred `for performance and interoperability reasons, it's the recommended mysql lib in PHP.`

> Similarly, what happens if the DB server crashes before mysql_query("COMMIT")? Would the transaction be "rolled back"?

It's easier that an application program crashes rather than a DB server. Any non committed transaction will be rolled back.

Also a transaction [can be rolled back because it can't acquire a lock within a certain timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html).

> The timeout in seconds an InnoDB transaction may wait for a row lock before giving up. The default value is 50 seconds. A transaction that tries to access a row that is locked by another InnoDB transaction will hang for at most this many seconds before issuing the following error:
>
> **ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction**

Comment: So unless I'm using prepared statements or an object oriented notation, there is really no need for me to switch to mysqli? Why is there so much confusion over this? It seems like a lot of people believe that you cannot use mysql/ext for transactions. IE, if you look up mysql vs mysqli a big seeling point for mysqli seems to be transactions when they are possible using mysql... Is there a "gotcha" I should know about or are people just being fanboys?

Comment: @billmalarky: You should got with mysqli for performance and interoperability reasons, it's the recommended mysql lib in PHP. The mysql (w/o the i), is not getting much attention any longer, you mostly run over old code.

Comment: @stivlo Also, if the DB server crashes are you kind of in a pickle? As in, maybe the transaction will commit and maybe not depending on luck  (I'm under the impression that perfect ACID is not possible).

Comment: @stilvo, when the connection drops the transaction will **always** be rolled back, because a rollback will be issued upon reconnect, regardless of timeouts.

Comment: You'd be surprised at the number of programmers who think that a database transaction is the SSL portion of a web transaction (buying). Not many people actually know what a "db transaction" is in the first place. Sad, but true. T-Up for Stivlo btw.

Comment: @billmalarky, That is nonsense, if the DB server crashes the transaction will be rolled back, because non-commited transactions are not yet saved in the DB, they are in suspension and will be removed from perjury when the server restarts.

Comment: @hakre Yes, I'll be switching to an object oriented mysqli setup, but I don't have time to update all my code right now and only need transactions for certain scripts.

Comment: Guys, regarding my pseudocode, how does it look? That is, if I put actual sql query strings in for the $query variables.  I will be using this exact style in my web application if it looks good!

Comment: You say "unless I'm using prepared statements" like it's something you wouldn't do.  Personally, I hold the opinion that prepared statements are the only really safe way to protect yourself from SQL Inection.  When using mysql_real_escape_string, it's way too easy to forget to use it, or naively leave it on on something you think is an integer (because in PHP all variables are dynamic).  If you only ever use prepared statements, then SQL injection is impossible.

Comment: @billmalarky: mysqli has a [procedural interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.summary.php) as well, comparable to mysql. mysql is just really old, the [recommendation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) is there for a long, long time: *"**Note:** If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is **strongly** recommended that you use the mysqli extension instead."*

Comment: @billmalarky if the first query failed, do you need to execute the other queries? Maybe you can run your queries in a method and throw an exception to jump out of the method in case of problems, the controlling (parent) method would deal with transactions instead. So you separate the concerns too.

Comment: @kibbee Your point is heard. I'm currently using mysql_real_escape_string on every variable in my query strings (even integers) to play it safe. I also put single quotes around integer variables which is a huge no-no but I'm doing this to play everything safe while I buy myself time to completely update the code with PDO or mysqli prepared statements. Don't kill me please!

Comment: @hakre I agree with you about mysqli, I think now my post gives the wrong impression that I back mysql extension, I edit the post to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: @stivlo: Not at all, I just wanted to make visible that there is an alternative available that should be used instead (not only because of transactions or not).

Comment: @stivlo No I actually wouldn't want the other queries to execute, because it would corrupt my data (IE when a new user account is created I have to add data to the user table, then insert a new row into the user stats table, and I wouldn't want to have a random user stats table row not tied to a user table row if the first insert failed). Isn't this the entire point of using transactions though? Wouldn't I just be reinventing the wheel trying to accomplish this another way? Thanks.

Comment: @billmalarky, Also I would have to say that I recommend PDO over MySQLi because it doesn't tie you to a database.  Although the odds of switching databases is small, it's still there.  Not only that, but being most a .Net programmer, I scoff at the thought of having my database calls tied to a specific vendor's database. It's wrong on so many levels.

Comment: @hakre I know that the mysql/ext is on it's way out, but basically this is just buying me time. I don't have a week right now to go back and update code before I need something to show. My plan is to release what I have now, and then go back and update the project over time.

Comment: @billmalarky If you execute them or not, they won't corrupt your data since you rollback, is just only a waste to execute them if you know already that you're going to roll back. What I am suggesting was a way to split the transaction logic and the query logic in two different methods rather than keeping them mixed. However, also your system is fine, you'll just do a few useless queries and then roll them back.

Comment: @stivlo Yes, this makes complete sense. Definitely an optimization I'll keep in mind. Though right now simplicity is more important than fine tuning and opening up more chances for problems etc for my current project.

Comment: @Kibbee Thank you for the suggestion. And believe me, I'll heed it. The last thing I want is to learn mysqli only to have the php team shove something new down my throat later ;-), PDO seems like the safest learning investment in terms of sticking around time and flexibility from what I read.

Comment: @billmalarky: which will never happen, but I fully understand your point ;)

Comment: @hakre Hahahaha well it's a work in progress right ;-) Delaying the inevitable. It's the human condition, with you know, being mortal and all.

Comment: @hakre a 3 year followup. I never did get the time to switch to PDO on that project though I worked on it intermittently for years. It was a mess of procedural code so you can see how updating the db api would prove challenging hahahah. It concerns me that I continue to get reputation points for this question in 2014 (just got 5 pts which brought me back here)...

Comment: Here it is, almost the year 2017, and this answer with supporting commentary has made today a much better day. Yes, "mysql is on its way out," but for programs that still use it (mine), it's nice to hear that transactions can be accomplished without rewriting the whole script in PDO. Thank you @billmalarky and other contributors.